# Where can I find more diamonds or champagne?

Tags: dead-island

I need a bunch of diamonds to make a mod, and the only way I know of is to turn in champagne as exchange, but so far I've only found one bottle (I forgot where).  Where can I get more champagne and diamonds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Multiple fridges in the kitchen area of the Hotel.  (This is a one time event, you cannot go back to the kitchen after the quest there is complete)
- Two refrigerators in the abandoned house also known as the Square near the southern edge of the Moresby map. You can fast travel to and from here to farm them.
- Refrigeration units inside the Supermarket.
- Three refrigerators in the Laboratory, two in the room where Dr. West is standing, and one fridge in the corner room down the hall through the two double doors.
- Two refrigerators within the hut on the Eastern edge of the River Village, at the top of the hill.

The fridges in the Hotel was where I found the most. I think I got about half a dozen bottles of champagne from there the first time I went through.

The best way to get champagne is to fast travel between the Abandoned House and the Laboratory, checking the fridges at each location every time.

[Source](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Champagne)

Comment: Seconded on the hotel. Probably got 12 bottles on my first run through (because I'm an obsessive kleptomaniac).

Answer (score 2):

You can find about 3-7 Bottles of Champagne in the Supermarket in the City Of Moresby, remember the path when you visit(-ed?) it. make multiple runs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

With the kitchen (if you have the patience), you can run back and forth to the security room and the fridges will respawn, although this doesn't happen every time.

To me it was worth it. Just remember that you will not be able to come back and with a chance to get anywhere between 6-12 champagne bottles each go.

Answer (score 1):

When I did the kitchen I found 1 or 2 champagne bottles in the first room, then when you get close to that dead body with his arm cut off next too a extra snack, the guy says there's a mob of them in there... I went in there and got like 8 9 more champagne bottles.