# What do I do with diamonds?

Tags: dead-island

After finishing the quests that take me through the hotel to get to the parking lot, I accumulated a fair number of champagne bottles, which I dutifully turned in for diamonds.  Now I've got 8 diamonds.

The diamonds sell well to merchants (about $1500 iirc), but I've held off on selling any, since rare items like that usually have a better use than being sold for cash.

From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/where-can-i-find-more-diamonds-or-champagne) I see that diamonds are needed for a mod later on, which does not surprise me.  What mod is it, and how many diamonds will I need?

Can I sell some of my diamonds and still have enough for late game, or should I hoard every single one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually five different mod's:

- [Developer's No. 1](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Developer%27s_No._1_Craft)
- [Developer's No. 2](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Developer%27s_No._2_Craft)
- [Developer's No. 3](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Developer%27s_No._3_Craft)
- [Developer's No. 4](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Developer%27s_No._4_Craft)
- [Developer's No. 666](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Developer%27s_No._666_Craft)

Each mod requires 5 diamonds to craft, which means you will need **25** diamonds to craft every single one of them. So I would recommend keeping them until you have enough to craft them all.

Comment: I've found that craft No. 666 was quite useless.  Low damage, sucks up all your stamina, and low durability.

Comment: I've crafted all 5 of them. 666 is indeed quite useless. The homerun bat (No. 2) has a comically amazing knockback effect, but is otherwise hard to use as it's durability is poor and is expensive to repair. The other three are all only good in the hands of Logan as they also lack durability and are expensive. In the hands of Logan, No. 4 is AMAZING and when he is properly specced, he can throw it into a group of zombies and instantly kill all of them.